# android web browser does not open url

Tags: java, android, webview

i want to open url through browser but when i click on button it does not open the url please tell me where i made mistake.
here is the code of java file.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    EditText editText;
    WebView webView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);



    }


    public void Goo(View view){
        String url = editText.getText().toString();
        webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
}
```

here is xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter url"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edittext"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="Goo"
        android:text="Go"
        android:id="@+id/but"
        />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

when i click on button it does not open the page and in the logcat it show message like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In activity just copy paste the following code...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button1, button2;
    EditText editText;
    WebView webView;
    String url;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
        button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.but1);
        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                url=editText.getText().toString();
                url="http://"+url;
                loadUrl(url);
            }
        });
       button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               url="http://www.stackoverflow.com";
               loadUrl(url);
           }
       });

    }

    public void loadUrl(String url) {
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            webView.loadUrl(url);
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

and in manifest file..
add these two lines..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

In xml, I added,

```
 <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Go"
            android:id="@+id/but"
            />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="fb"
        android:id="@+id/but1"
        />
```

Comment: @MasoomBacha..my code is perfectly fine..it is self tested code...i think there might be problem in your url

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            loadUrl(url);
        }
    });

Comment: loadUrl(url); in this line url in brace is red and show error

Comment: @MasoomBacha..your all error is removed now...in my updated answer

Comment: all error removed but it still not open any url its show in logcat which i upload in my question

Comment: please tell me what is the solution of this when i click on button it nothing happend

Comment: @MasoomBacha..you are taking url from edit text input..so you have to make sure that..you are typing the correct url in edit text or just debug or make Log.i() function to look on your edit text value

Comment: @MasoomBacha...this is the fully tested complete answer of your question...tested in my side...and working like a charm....cheers!

Comment: @MasoomBacha...this is the fully tested complete answer of your question...tested in my side...and working like a charm....cheers!

Comment: @MasoomBacha..have you tested the new updated code in your side?

Comment: can i add you on fb?

Comment: @MasoomBacha...Sorry dear.. i don't have account on fb till yet because i hate social networking...sorry...

Comment: @MasoomBacha..As you can see from my stackoverflow community profile...  I am from pune..

Comment: i want to add one button on this layout i want when i click on this button it open the facebook how can i do this.

Comment: i have do some thing like this but when i click on the button its suggest other browser to open this page

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In your `onCreate`  :

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // call your Goo method here 
    }
});
```

Comment: what's not working? can you post your updated codes?